# Does tortoise or ankh svn have log dump capability?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, changelog

I'd like to include revision history in a menu system of my builds so that users can see it and it's auto-built from the svn repository before each build. My team doesn't have the core svn, only tortoise and ankh. I'd rather not have to go through configuration of it on each machine we use just for this feature if one of the tools we already have can do it.

I'm looking for something that does ANY full revision log dump like

svn log
svn log --xml
svn log -v

but built into ankh or tortoise.

i've been searching their documentation and websites with no luck so far, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TortoiseSVN doesn’t have the ability to do this, and I doubt Ankh does either.  The command line is the way to do it.  If you don’t want to install a command-line client on every machine, you could consolidate your build process so that there is a dedicated build machine which does it.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this the other day, and came up empty (we're using the exact same setup here).

If we both put in a feature request, it would carry more weight. ;)

Comment: @Jon -- well hopefully someone on here knows a good way and we'll find an answer without waiting for a new release of one of these products.

Comment: vote for it here: http://feedback.ankhsvn.net/pages/3267-general/suggestions/360408-implement-change-log-dumping they are saying they'd rather me have to download a seperate tool for this, instead of implement it in ankh.